Why is Celery Beat scheduler still running after it expires in Django Celery?
PeriodicTask.objects.create(
    interval=interval,
    crontab=crontab,
    clocked=clocked, 
    name=data["name"],
    task=data["task"], # dropdown
    args=json.dumps(json.loads(data["args"])),
    one_off=True if schedule_type == "clocked" else False,
    expires=datetime.strptime(data["expires"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') if data["expires"] else None
)

It's still running after the set expiration time.
It's not a calling function, but it's hit worker.
Ex: in the worker terminal:
[2024-07-22 07:06:16,334: INFO/MainProcess] Task test[390404a1-9814-4208-85a2-6e1269bc09d9] received
[2024-07-22 07:06:16,334: INFO/MainProcess] Discarding revoked task: test[390404a1-9814-4208-85a2-6e1269bc09d9]

And in Celery Beat Terminal:
[2024-07-22 07:06:16,327: WARNING/MainProcess] 390404a1-9814-4208-85a2-6e1269bc09d9 has an expiration date in the past (16.325898s ago).

We assume this is intended, and so we have set the expiration date to 0 instead.

According to RabbitMQ's documentation:

"Setting the TTL to 0 causes messages to be expired upon reaching a queue unless they can be delivered to a consumer immediately."
If this was unintended, please check the code that published this task.```

